# Bash script to loop through remote directory and pipe files 1 at a time to CURL

Tags: bash, loops, curl, pipe, remote-server

I am trying to transfer all files residing in a specified directory on Server1 to Server3 via a script running on Server2.

The transfer to Server3 has to happen through an API and thus must use the following CURL call:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/xfer/$name\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary @$f
```

If it is just 1 file, I can do it successfully, but i'm trying to iterate through the directory on Server1 and send the file directly to the CURL call. So far I've got:

```
files="( $(ssh me@server1 ls dir/*) )"
while read f 
do
  name=$(basename ${f})
  curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/xfer/$name\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary @$f
done <<< "$files"
```

The loop seems to be reading the "(" from the array of files into the 1st file name, which obviously causes a problem. I can't get beyond that to be able to tell if POSTING the current file in the loop via `--data-binary` will actually do what I think (or am hoping) it will.

Any ieas?

Comment: Why do you have those extra outer parentheses at all?

Comment: to create an array so that filenames with spaces are not broken up into multiple strings, but that doesn't seem to be working anyway as `echo ${#files[@]}` returns `1` even if there are multiple files. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error in the original message was enclosing the ssh command with `"()"`.  I am working on a similar issue.  In the past I've used Rsync but I want a solution that doesn't require installing extra software.  Here is an example that I'm working with to move files off of a Nodejs dev server to backup, running in Bash on Debian:

```
files=$(ssh chris@estack ls ~/tmp/gateway)
#echo $files
for FILE in $files
do

  if [[ "$FILE" = "node_modules" || "$FILE" = ".git" ]]
  then
    echo "skip $FILE";
    continue
  fi

  echo Copy ~/tmp/gateway/$FILE
  #scp -Cpr chris@estack:~/tmp/gateway/$FILE ~/tmp/tmp
done
```

Comment: Does this work if you have file names containing spaces? My guess is that a file name like `my data.csv` will be treated as 2 files,`my` and `data.csv` and you'll get a `no such file` error, but more importantly, `my data.csv` will not be copied. That's what I was running into anyway.

Comment: You are right.  My final code uses this pattern: `scp -Cpr chris@estack:~/tmp/gateway/"$FILE" ~/tmp/tmp`.  Also, note that many recommend this patter: `scp -Cpr chris@estack:~/tmp/gateway/"${FILE}" ~/tmp/tmp`.  For details see something like this: [Google's Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html)